# Portable IRC multi-computer usage with same user

Tags: windows, portable, irc, multiple-instances

I use an IRC client both at home and at work. I would like both computers to use the same user (for IDENT purposes and avoiding multiple nicks etc)

Typically, the home computer is always-on, and is IDENTified as my user. The work computer is connected only when I'm actually at work. I have quite a few scripts and settings, and would like to keep everything in one place, which is why I use a portable client (specifically mIRC in portable mode for now, but not necessarily limited to this client) in a dropbox dir.

Currently, I just opened two users, both with IDENTities (i.e. nick and nick|work), one for each computer. This way I can keep them both idle.

What I would *like* to do is something like the following:

- The first client that gets online identifies and performs all its remote scripts. No Problem.
- If another client tries to connect, but the name is already taken (by the previous client), disconnect the other (idling) client, and assume its identity.
- This should be able to go on for as many clients as I wish - as long as only one client is active.

I was thinking of maybe creating a script to "disconnect-idle", which will send a special message to the idling client. This client will parse the message, and will disconnect itself from the server if everything is as specified.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?
Code samples (mIRC scripts or others) would be much appreciated.

Comment: The usual approach is to use a so called [BNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software)).

Comment: Tagging "Windows" since Mirc was mentioned (personally I use irssi+tmux+SSH in Linux for this).

Comment: I wasn't necessarily referring to windows only, even though it is currently my client on my windows boxes. I'll take @OliverSalzburg's advice and look into a BNC setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mIRC has a well featured if not quirky scripting language.  I'm sure what you want to do can be programmed with mIRC scripts, but it's been a long time since I've played with mIRC (I tend to prefer kvIRC these days as it is cross platform).

Take @Oliver Salzburg's advice and run a BNC on your home computer (I recommend ZNC), and set up the necessary port forwarding to reach it from outside your home network.  It is a bit involved but well worth it if you are a serious IRC user.

The BNC maintains connection to an IRC server, and functions as an "IRC proxy."  Your IRC client connects to the BNC, and you sort of have to "login" to the BNC through your IRC client.  After you do that, you then see your real servers and channels.  BNCs have features such as replaying messages that were received while you were disconnected from the BNC.

Comment: Even run the BNC from a 'shell' somewhere and then just connect to it whichever client/location you are in.